# Could not uninstall Confer application on my mac

Tags: applications, macos

Today, somehow the application "Confer" got installed in my mac. I am not able to delete that application as moving it to trash says "The item “Confer” can’t be moved to the Trash because it’s open." I tried following the instructions given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306512/uninstall-confer-app)
, but still no luck. Could someone please help me get rid of this application? I tried to kill using activity monitor and kill -9 command as well, but nothing is getting rid of this application. I am not sure if this will have an impact to my device, would really like to get rid of this one.

PS:  Mac OS version - 10.13.6

Comment: @NimeshNeema I tried the steps mentioned in that link, but could not get the issue resolved. So, I opened a new question. Also, the here hyperlink in my description points to the existing question.

Comment: Does this help? Would appear it needs to be uninstalled from Recovery - https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/26398/carbonblack-6-0-4-70328-makes-macos-high-sierra-10-13-2-fail Also, it would appear that this is a corporate endpoint structure. Is yours a managed machine, or did you buy it 2nd hand & not completely wipe it?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks :) That link was useful. Rebooting Mac in Safe mode helps in deleting the confer application.

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting mac in safe mode let the confer app be moved to trash.